# How can import a database which is not exist yet in bash shell?

Tags: postgresql, import

Export database named `english` in bash command:

```
pg_dump --no-owner --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/english  > /tmp/database.sql
```

Now i enter into psql and drop the database `english`:

```
psql -U postgres
drop database english;
```

And exit.

Now i want to import the database `english` which is not exist.

```
psql -U postgres -d english  < /tmp/database.sql
#it can't work,error  
psql: error: FATAL:  database "english" does not exist
```

It can work to import the whole database after creating `english` database first:

```
psql -U postgres
create database english;
press ctrl+d to exit 
#execute in bash shell command
psql -U postgres -d english  < /tmp/database.sql
```

How can import a database which is not exist yet in bash shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a plain format dump like you do, you'd have to create the dump with the `--create` option, so that it contains a `CREATE DATABASE` statement:

```bash
pg_dump --create ... -f database.sql english
```

To restore such a dump, connect to database `postgres`:

```bash
psql -d postgres database.sql
```

If you were using a custom format dump (which I recommend), you could specify `--create` when you restore the dump.